# How to open a port from a running docker conatiner

Tags: docker, port, jupyter-notebook

I am running a docker container and I am running my image in the container. I need to connect to Jupyter notebook's web application in a browser. I am able to run the Jupyter notebook in docker but I am unable to run it in the browser. I assume it is because I have not exposed the port with which I am trying to access the notebook in the browser. However, I cannot rebuild my image from scratch, so I am looking for an option to open the port from my running container.

Any help for the same is appreciated.

Comment: docker run -d -p 80:80 image

Comment: I executed the command to run the image `docker run -p 80:8810 image_name` and then executed the command `docker exec -it conatiner_name bash` to run the container. However, the problem still exists.

Comment: With `docker run -p 80:8810 image_name` you "transform" you image into running container and with `docker exec -it conatiner_name bash` you attached to container. 
run your container in `-d` detached mode: `docker run -d -p 80:80 image_name` and check notebook in the browser.

Comment: Are you running this natively on Linux or using Docker for Mac/Windows?

Comment: I am running docker on a Windows machine

Comment: @VladoDemcak: I ran the container in a detached mode as per your instructions, notebook is still not connected to the browser

Comment: @Vasanti Are you using `docker pull jupyterhub/jupyterhub` or you have your own image? Did you change port from default 8000 to 8810 somewhere? 
try: `docker pull jupyterhub/jupyterhub` and after that `docker run -d --name jupyterhub -p 8080:8000  jupyterhub/jupyterhub jupyterhub` and in browser visit `https://localhost:8080`

Comment: @VladoDemcak: I installed Jupyter notebook in my container using `pip install jupyter` and then executed the command `jupyter notebook --port 8810`. Even if I try to run without specifying the port and try running the application in browser, it does not get connected.

Comment: @Vasanti if you are installing jupyter while your container is running you need to expose port 8810 before installation or start. so run your container with `-p 8080:8810` then install or make sure jupyter is running and if port is not blocked you should be able to see jup. in browser on port 8080. Your configuration can also has blocking for incomming trafic so you can try `"--ip=0.0.0.0"` like in http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html

Comment: @VladoDemcak: I executed the command `docker run -p 8080:8810 image_name` followed by `docker exec -it conatiner_name bash`. I reinstalled Jupyter and re-ran the command `jupyter notebook --port 8810` and tried to connect via the web-browser at http://ip_address:8810. However, the connection was not established.

Comment: try with `jupyter notebook --port=8810 --ip=0.0.0.0`

Comment: still not working

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone could help me solve this problem